# java.sql.SQLException : Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, mysql

I have code like this

```
String sql_kode_kategori = "select kategori from data_kategori \n" +
                                   "where kode_kategori = ?";
    try{
        pst = (PreparedStatement) koneksiMySQL.GetConnection().prepareStatement(sql_kode_kategori);
        pst.setString(1, (String)cbKategori.getSelectedItem());
        rst2 = pst.executeQuery();
        rst2.next();

        stat = (Statement) koneksiMySQL.GetConnection().createStatement();
        String sql_insert = "INSERT INTO data_pasal VALUES ('"+jTPasal.getText() + "','"+jTIsi_Pasal.getText()+"'"
                + ",'"+jTHukuman.getText()+"','"+jTDenda.getText()+"','"+rst2.getString(1)+"')";
        stat.executeUpdate(sql_insert);
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data CES Berhasil Ditambahkan");
        ClearField();
        TampilTabel();

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

i tried to get kode_kategori with kategori but that error appear, please help me

Comment: First thing to do: stop inserting values directly into your SQL. Use parameterized SQL, as you're already doing for the query part.

Comment: If rst2.next() returns false, there is no data for rst2.getString(1). You need to check for result as if(rst2.next()) {

Comment: can you give me some example on source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `\n` from your query:

```
 String sql_kode_kategori = "select kategori from data_kategori where kode_kategori = ?";
```

Try to verify this `(String)cbKategori.getSelectedItem()` variable does contain right value.

Comment: @Pramesty Jaya Try to verify this (String)cbKategori.getSelectedItem() variable does contain right value.

Comment: that's part work perfectly, nothing wrong on that part

Comment: oh god, my bad. I want to get kode_kategori use kategori, i use wrong query. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

If `rst2.next()` returns false, there is no data for `rst2.getString(1)`. You need to check for result as

```
if(rst2.next()) { 
    stat = (Statement) koneksiMySQL.GetConnection().createStatement();
    String sql_insert = "INSERT INTO data_pasal VALUES ('"+jTPasal.getText() + "','"+jTIsi_Pasal.getText()+"'"
            + ",'"+jTHukuman.getText()+"','"+jTDenda.getText()+"','"+rst2.getString(1)+"')";
    stat.executeUpdate(sql_insert);
} else {
  // handle invalid category
}
```

Comment: program can't run with that way

Comment: ? Please explain. Do you get errors? Not compiling?